# Rectangle with radius clipping taking huge performance hit, advice?

Tags: performance, windows-phone-7

I am currently programming an App, and I have been testing it on a Nokia Omnia 800 (as well as in the simulator).

Currently I have a ScrollViewer with several images, I need to clip the scrollviewer so that the corners are rounded:

[image: Like this:]

I have done that with:

```
<ScrollViewer.Clip>
<RectangleGeometry  Rect="1, 1, 445, 119" RadiusX="12" RadiusY="12"/>
</ScrollViewer.Clip>
```

Problem is, the app takes a significantly performance hit, and the slider is not very smooth.
As soon as I take the RadiusX="12" RadiusY="12" away, the slider get super smooth.

Is there any way I could try to improve the performance with the rounded corners? Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get the best performance if you can edit the original images.

Saving that you could manipulate a copy of the image and then load that. Have a look at [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) for some help with this.

Finally you could create an image (or 4 - 1 in each corner) that you display over the top of the image and which is mostly transparent but has rounded area in the corner which is the same color as the background.

As an additional pointer, you'll also create apps which look more like they belong on the phone by gaining an understanding of the [Metro Design Language](http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/tutorials/windows-phone-7/metro/). Hint: rounded corners look make your app look like you've ported it straight from iOS without understanding the basics of Windows Phone. ;)

Comment: Thx for the help! I think I ll try the images in each corner!We just choose not to go with a metro design layout.